# How to Get current URL in another class from WebView which is in MainActivity

Tags: android, webview, push-notification, android-webview

When I get a push notification, I want to check current url in WEBVIEW (which is in MainActivity.java) from another class FcmMessagingService.java .

If currentUrl == mentioned URL, I want to perform specific task.

Can you tell how to get **currenturl** from MainActivity?

```
   public class FcmMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();

if (currenturl == "www.example.com")) {
   // task    
}else{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get currenturl do this

`currenturl= mWebView.getUrl();`

Replace `currenturl = "www.example.com"`

with `currenturl.equals("www.example.com")`

Comment: how to get currenturl?

Comment: Are you sending current url from the notification?

Comment: No, when I get notification, I just want to check if I i'm on specific page. If yes then perform specific task (which in this case is reload  current URL)

Comment: Okay, just found out one more to it, Webview page is in MainActivity.java & I'm performing this check in FcmMessagingService.java file. How to perform this task there?

Comment: You can use a local broadcast manager to send data to the activity.

Comment: Can you tell how to do so? Code is preferred